# Is there any way to export in glb while keeping the NLA separation?

Tags: animation

Is there any way to export in glb while keeping the NLA separation?

I am creating a model with multiple NLA animations on one part.
I am creating NLAs that are separated for each movement (image 1),
When I export the NLA in glb format and then import it back into Blender, the separation is removed and the model reverts to a series of NLAs. (Image 2)

I would like to know if there is any way to do this.

Translated with DeepL.com (free version)
[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks like the separate animations are still there, but embedded in what I assume are single keyframes, which should be relatively easy to clean up. Not a solution, but a potential workaround. Can you post a screenshot of the individual frames on the timelines? (Great avatar, by the way :)

Comment: thank you,Screenshots of the timeline have been added. Is this the correct one?
(Moomin is cute :))